# Undefined reference to getaddrinfo

Tags: c, winsock

I have been getting this error for quite some time now and Google has not been of much help either.

I am a newbie to Winsock programming and trying to learn from online resources. I am trying to build a simple server using details on MSDN website. Whenever I compile the code (MinGW), I get the error mentioned in the title (`Undefined reference to getaddrinfo`). Below is the code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#define WINVER WindowsXP

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    #define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with the following command:

```
gcc msdn_np.c -o msdn_np.exe -lWS2_32
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isn't it the same problem as here ?

http://programmingrants.blogspot.com/2009/09/tips-on-undefined-reference-to.html

Basically do not forget to link with Ws2_32.lib (the message is from the linker, so that's should be the reason) but you seem to be doing that already.

... if you're working with an old version of windows programming tools say to it you have a version higher than XP by putting `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` before including headers (unlikely to still be necessary nowaday, but maybe).

The could be other simple problems. Normal (Unix) convention for libraries is to prepend them with lib. Henceforth, meaning for -lWS32_32 would be to search for a file whose name is  `libWS32_32.a`. It is likely it does not find it because it's missing the path to the directory containing the library. You could add a -L followed by the path to the correct directory. Alternatively you do not even need -l to link with a library, just putting the full path to the library (in this case the real name of the file as it appears on filesystem) should also work.

The problem can also be path related. For instance problems can occurs if path to library contains spaces. If this is so you can try putting you library files in a directory with a simpler name.

Please give use some feedback of your actual configuration (in which directory is the library file) and what you actually tried. You could also tries setting LIBS and LIBPATH environment variables (simplest way is probably to do that from a makefile).

Comment: But I am linking the library Ws2_32 (refer third last line in OP) and still I am getting the problem, that is what is frustrating.

Comment: I guess working with NPP and mingw was tricky. I changed to CodeBlocks and the changed the linker settings to include Ws2_32.dll and now its working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

Take a look at the stuff under "remarks".  It is possible that you are trying to use an ANSI-C version of the function when you aren't compiling as ANSI-C.

Comment: Not helpful either. The error is persisting. Tried the GetAddrInfoW, but with little success. Even tried modifying the order of includes but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

`WindowsXP` was defined in `w32api.h`, you have to `#include <w32api.h>` before your `#define WINVER`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is _WIN32_WINNT. Check ws2tcpip.h header file for the minimum version to use `getaddrinfo()`.