# C error: undefined reference to

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I have created the following socket server in C (Windows) making use of the library Winsock.

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int __cdecl main(void) {

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL; 
struct addrinfo hints;

char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iSendResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if(iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if(iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if(ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n",  WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Set up a TCP listening socket
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
freeaddrinfo(result), // to free the memory allocated by getaddrinfo function

// Listen on a socket
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) { // SOMAXCONN indicates the backlog value, maximum length of the queue of pending connections to accept
    printf("Listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Accept connection on a socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if(ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
closesocket(ListenSocket); // No longer need server socket

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if(iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        if(iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    } else if(iResult == 0) {
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    } else {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
} while(iResult > 0);

// Shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closessocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile it I get the following error for every function from the Winsock library:

```
C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOwFjRF.o:socketServer.c:(.text+0x4a): undef
ined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
```

I added the directory where the Winsock library is to the path but it seems that I need to do something else. Does anyone have any idea about the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is this error at link time or compile time? This looks like one of two things. Either you need to include another file, or you are not linking against a required library. I believe you are experiencing a link error, and you should check these pragmas. #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

Comment: What's your build command?

Comment: It is a link error. I have already checked with all those pragmas but I get the same error.

Comment: I have added the directory of the lib folder for the pragmas in the Path variable but it looks like the compiler does not recognize the libraries name.

Comment: I just pasted this source into a VS2012 empty project, and it builds correctly, link and all. What toolchain are you using?

Comment: I think you would need to add `-lwsock32` to get your compilation successful apart from the `lws2_32` as suggested

Comment: I use MinGW (gcc -o serverSocket serverSocket.c)

Comment: With `MinGW`, please try with `gcc -o serverSocker serverSocket.c -lws2_32 -lwsock32`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with whether gcc honors `#pragma comment(lib, "libname")` it probably does, but a fully specified library name on the link line of your makefile couldn't hurt. You could always crank up the verbosity level of the link step to see exactly what it is trying to include in the link, and where it comes from.

Comment: pass `-Wunknown-pragmas` into your build command to check if that pragma is supported

Comment: by doing 'gcc -o serverSocker serverSocket.c -lws2_32 -lwsock32' I reduce the number of errors from 50 to 5 but I still have problems with the 'getaddrinfo', 'freeaddrinfo' and 'closesocket' functions.

Comment: yes, pragma is supported by gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the compilation successful, you would require to perform the following changes:

1. In your source file, you would have to define `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` before the inclusion of headers. Please refer to this earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220190/undefined-reference-to-getaddrinfo) for more details.
2. There is a typo in the sources. Please replace `closessocket` to `closesocket` at line no. 121 of your source file.
3. Compile with the following command

   `gcc -o socketServer socketServer.c -lws2_32 -lwsock32 -L $MinGW\lib`

Where `$MinGW` is the installation directory of MinGW softare

With these changes, I am able to compile your code successfully.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your information. It helped me a lot and my program is running now.