# undefined reference to imp_getaddrinfo

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

I have been learning how to program networking in windows via **C++**, it's going well except I have encountered a problem of which I was unable to solve for about 3-4 days now, I am using **Dev-C++ 5.5.3(Orwell)**, the compiler is **TDM-GCC 4.7.1**.
I've added **"-lwsock32"** (without the quotes) to the linker parameters. all works well
except the **"freeaddrinfo"** and **"getaddrinfo"**, here is what it says on 2 of these functions.

> undefined reference to `*imp*_getaddrinfo@16'
>
> undefined reference to `*imp*_freeaddrinfo@4'

I have read somewhere that it it requires me to define the version of windows I'd like to
use, so I defined the **_WINNT_WIN32 0x0601** as required, but with no avail.
**Here is my code(shortened):**

```
#define _WINNT_WIN32 0x0601
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
// server

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;                                
    ZeroMemory(&wsaData,sizeof(wsaData));
    int nResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
    if(nResult != 0)
     {
                printf(TEXT("WSAStartup function failed, value: %d\n"),nResult);
                Sleep(5000);
                return 0001;
     }
    else
      printf(TEXT("WSAStartup function has succeeded! value: %d\n"),nResult);
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    nResult = getaddrinfo(NULL,DEFAULT_PORT,&hints,&result);
    if(nResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo did not return 0... failure...");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0002;
    }
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family,result->ai_socktype,result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket():%ld\n",WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0003;
    }
    nResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr,(int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if(nResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("bindfailed with error %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0004;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if(listen(ListenSocket,SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("lISTEN FAILED WITH ERROR %LD\n",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
    }
    return 1337^9001;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220190/undefined-reference-to-getaddrinfo .

Comment: Yes I've read it, but it was no help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure that you define _WIN32_WINNT in your preprocessor definition, and use `-lWs2_32` [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of an unresolved external. The function you are trying to use is [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx). Scroll down to the bottom of that documentation link to the section headed requirements. It tells you that you need to include `Ws2tcpip.h` to declare the function, and you've already done that. But it also tells you that you need to use the `Ws2_32.lib` import library to provide the definition of the function. That step is what you have missed.

So to solve the problem you need to link the `Ws2_32` library, by adding `-lWs2_32` to your command line options.