# How to use getaddrinfo() on windows

Tags: c, compilation, winsock, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to build my APP with mingw+msys.

My code usee winsock. When I compile it I take following error message:

```
$ gcc -o sample sample.c -lws2_32
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsdWlQR.o:sample.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code that is migrated from Linux with changing some headers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    printf("Hello world with winsock");

    int sock;
    char *hostAddress;
    struct addrinfo hints,*res;
    int err;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1",12345,&hints,&res);

    printf("getaddrinfo %s\n",strerror(errno));
    printf("getaddrinfo : %s \n",gai_strerror(err));


    struct sockaddr_in *addr;
    struct addrinfo *rp;
    for (rp = res; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)rp->ai_addr; 
        printf("dstPort  = %d\n",ntohs(addr->sin_port));
        printf("dstAddr  = %s\n",inet_ntoa((struct in_addr)addr->sin_addr));
        hostAddress = inet_ntoa((struct in_addr)addr->sin_addr);    
    }
    WSACleanup( );                                    

}
```

How can I use `gettarrinfo()` in Windows?

This is the additional information that message is changed after trying  dgreenday's article.

```
sample.c:22:2: warning: passing argument 2 of 'getaddrinfo' makes pointer from i
nteger without a cast [enabled by default]
  getaddrinfo("124.0.0.1",12345,&hints,&res);
  ^
In file included from sample.c:4:0:
c:\mingw\include\ws2tcpip.h:391:12: note: expected 'const char *' but argument i
s of type 'int'
 int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
```

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220190/undefined-reference-to-getaddrinfo

Comment: I've done linking Ws2_32.Lib and tried to add `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` as this site said.Error massage changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you simply have an out of date SDK, and the import library supplied in your SDK does not include `getaddrinfo`. Your program, compiled the way you describe links fine on my mingw system.

Either update your mingw system, or create an import library that does contain `getaddrinfo`.

Note that:

```
getaddrinfo("124.0.0.1",12345,&hints,&res);
```

should be:

```
getaddrinfo("124.0.0.1","12345",&hints,&res);
```

And you are not checking for errors correctly. You must take notice of the value returned by `getaddrinfo`. It is not appropriate to ignore that and then go on to check `errno`.

Comment: I fixed to `getaddrinfo("124.0.0.1","12345",&hints,&res);` and went well.