# Resolve IP address by node name using WinSock APIs

Tags: c, windows, winsock

I need to resolve IP address by node name

Example:
Node Name = http://google.com/
How to resolve his IP address?

Comment: You probably should specify your platform.

Comment: Windows, winsock APIs

Comment: Please remove `sockets` `ip` & `endpoint` tags and add `winsock` `windows`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008864/how-to-use-getaddrinfo-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Use `getaddressinfo()` call to get valid IP-Addresses & Port numbers for a Domain-Service pair.

[Windows Docs : GetAddressInfo() : Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo)

For your case `http://google.com`

```
Domain : "google.com"
Service : "http" or "80" when port# is known
```

Comprehensive list of `Internet network services` check `/etc/services` ASCII Text file on Linux systems. Incomplete old copy [on clemson.edu](https://www.cs.clemson.edu/course/cpsc424/material/TCP%20UDP%20Services/etc-services.pdf)

Comment: And when the port is not known?

Comment: Then use service name; added a link in the post.